# No diffeomorphism that takes unit circle to unit square

Tags: differential-geometry, diffeomorphism

This is not a homework problem. I am trying to learn my own from John M. Lee's *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds*.

In Chapter 3, there is the problem 3-4

> Let $C \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ be the unit circle, and let $S \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ be the boundary of the square of side 2 centred at origin: $S= \lbrace (x,y) \colon \max(|x|,|y|)=1 \rbrace.$
> Show that there is a homeomorphism $F:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $F(C)=S$, but there is no diffeomorphism with the same property. [Hint: Consider what $F$ does to the tangent vector to a suitable curve in $C$].

I can construct a homeomorphism (by placing the circle inside the square and then every radial line intersects the square at exactly one point). But, I don't know how to do the rest of the problem or understand the hint.

I do not know how to write out what tangent space should be for the square. If there were a diffeomorphism then $F_\star$ is isomorphism between any two tangent space. If I show that the tangent space on the corner of square has dimension zero, would it solve problem?

Comment: Have you proved that $S$ is not a smooth submanifold of $\mathbb R^2$ yet?  If so, you could use that as a lemma.  Argue that if there was such a diffeomorphism $F$, then $S$ would neccessarily be a smooth submanifold of $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: And if you haven't proven that yet, I think that would be a great way to solve your problem.   I like to make this argument using hypothetical charts for $S$ and an application of the Implicit Function Theorem.

Comment: @Ryan Budney -- Thank you for commenting. No, I have not learned submanifolds yet. It is chapter 8 of the book. Does the tangent space at the corner have zero dimensions? I do not know how to prove it. How can I solve this problem with the things I know (defintion of smooth manifolds, maps and tangent space)? Thank you very much for help

Comment: What definition of "tangent space" are you using?

Comment: Show that $K$ and $\mathbb{S}^1$ are isomorphic in $\textbf{Top}$, but $K \not\in ob(\textbf{Diff})$.

Comment: @user1876508, I am afraid that that does not really mean anything :-/

Comment: @user1876508 is using language from catgegory theory and I believe his or her comment translates as "Show that $K$ and $\mathbb{S}^1$ are isomorphic in terms of topology (i.e. homeomorphic) but that $K$ is not a smooth manifold." See page 73 of Lee for more details.

Answer (score 20):

Here's a somewhat rigorous way to see this.  Let $\gamma$ be an arc in $C$ such that $F\circ \gamma(0)$ is the corner (1,1).  Then (assuming it goes clockwise) there are some functions $x$ and $y$ such that $F \circ \gamma(t) = (1,y(t))$ for $t< 0$ and $F \circ \gamma(t) = (x(t),1)$ for $t > 0$.  Thus $F_*\gamma'(t)$ is $(0,y'(t))$ for $t<0$ and $(x'(t),0)$ for $t > 0$.  Taking limits, this means that $F_*\gamma'(0) = 0$ contradicting that $\gamma'(0) \ne 0$.

Comment: How can you guarantee that $F \circ \gamma (t) = (1, y(t))$ for every $t<0$? I'm having a very hard time proving rigorously that we cannot have $t_1 < t_2 < 0$ such that $F \circ \gamma (t_1) = (1, y_1)$ and $F \circ \gamma (t_2) = (x_2, 1)$. Also, doesn't your phrasing implicitly assume that $F$ preserves orientation?

Comment: What does the "$*$" in $F_*\gamma'(t)$ mean?

Comment: Ah, on page 63 of Lee, he mentions that $F_*$ is used by some authors to mean the differential of $F$.

Comment: I suppose you are invoking the Inverse Function Theorem to conclude that $F_*$ is an isomorphism. The statement of that theorem is that *if* $\text{d}F$, where $F \colon \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$, is invertible at a point $p \in \mathbb R ^2$, then it is invertible in a neighbourhood. But does such a point exist? Since the (boundary of the) square is not a smooth manifold the standard "the differential of a differentiable map is a isomorphism" does not apply, right?

Comment: How do we know for sure that such an arc exists?

Answer (score 8):

The original statement above is *not* true.
That is a square *can* be given be a differentiable structure!

This follows from the more general theorem

Let $M$ and $N$ be topological manifolds that are homeomorphic with homeomorphism $h$.
If $N$ is also a smooth (differentiable) manifold, then a differentiable structure can be defined on $M$ via the pullback defined by $h$.

And with this differentiable structure on $M$, $h$ becomes a diffeomorphism from $M$ to $N$. That means $M$ and $N$ are diffeomorphic.

So the homeomorphism given above between the square and the circle can be used to pullback the usual differentiable structure on the circle to the square and with differentiable structure the homeomorphism becomes a diffeomorphism.

Note that this induced differentiable structure on the square is not compatible with the usual differentiable structure on $\mathbb{R}^2 = \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$. That the inclusion map from the square to $\mathbb{R}^2$ (identity map restricted to the square) will NOT be differentiable!

Comment: Why is this downvoted?  It is a correct statement that the square carries a differentiable structure as constructed in the above comment.  I also interpret the title of this post as an incorrect statement.  However, if "unit circle" and "unit square" mean being equipped with (topological) embeddings into $\mathbb{R}^2$, then since the square is not smoothly embedded by its set-theoretic identity, the statement is vacuous.  So the correct framing of the problem is that as given in the book (and in the body of the poster's question).  But there is good content in this response.

Answer (score 4):

A diffeomorphism would, among other things, induce an isomorphism between the respective tangent spaces. But look at the corners of the square, i.e., the points $\{(1,1),(1,0),(0,1),(0,0)\}$ (in the right coordinate system), and see what happens with the tangent space there. More specifically, the tangent space at the corners is not defined, but it must be the image of the tangent space of some point on the circle where the tangent space is defined. Basically, in the one-dimensional case, the tangent space (in one of its versions) is given in terms of the derivative $f'(t)\; \text{d}t$, but the derivative is not defined at the corners.