# Diffeomorphism between circle and square clarification

Tags: real-analysis, manifolds, diffeomorphism

I refer to the top answer on the following post: [No diffeomorphism that takes unit circle to unit square](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/54140/no-diffeomorphism-that-takes-unit-circle-to-unit-square).

If we assume that there is a diffeomorphism $f: \mathbb{R}^{2} \to \mathbb{R}^{2}$, we want to show that the image of the open unit ball can't be the open unit square. The strategy mentioned in the answer I've linked above is to show that this map (if it existed) should smoothly extend to the boundary, i.e. map the boundary of the open unit ball to the boundary of the square; however, we run into a problem at the corners of the square since the tangent vectors are perpendicular there, which implies that the differential (which we assume exists) must be zero, which contradicts our diffeomorphism assumption.

Can someone explain to me what tangent vectors in this context are, why they're perpendicular here, and why this implies that the differential is zero.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the point $(1,1)$ on the upper right-hand edge of the square. If $f:\mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R^2$ is such a diffeomorphism, consider the map $\gamma:t\mapsto e^{2i\pi t}$ where we assume without loss of generality that $f\circ \gamma(0)=(1,1)$ and that there is an $\epsilon>0$ such that $f\circ\gamma(-\epsilon,0)\subseteq \{(1,y):0<y<1\}$ and $f\circ\gamma(0,\epsilon)\subseteq \{(x,1):0<x<1\}.$

Then, $t\in (-\epsilon,0)\Rightarrow f\circ\gamma(t)=(1,\gamma_1(t))$ for some smooth $\gamma_1$ and $t\in (0,\epsilon)\Rightarrow f\circ\gamma(t)=(\gamma_2(t),1)$ for some smooth $\gamma_2$. Then we have, $(f\circ \gamma)'(t)=(0,\gamma_1'(0))$ and $(f\circ \gamma)'(t)=(\gamma_2'(0),0)$ which means on taking right and left hand limits, that $(f\circ \gamma)'(0)=0$. But now we have a contradiction because  $df$ is an isomorphism and $\gamma'(0)\neq 0.$

Comment: That makes sense. My question, more, is about relating the ideas of tangent vectors to this argument. What exactly are the tangent vectors here, and in what sense are they perpendicular? Are $f \circ \gamma: (-\epsilon, 0) \to \mathbb{R}^{2}$ and $f \circ \gamma: (0, \epsilon) \to \mathbb{R}^{2}$ two different tangent vectors?

Comment: $\gamma'(0)$ is a vector tangent to $S^1$ at $(1,0)$. The argument above (as I see it) is that $f\circ \gamma'(0)$ must be a vector tangent to the square at $(1,1)$ and the calculation showed that this is impossible. And it makes sense, because along the boundary of the square, the tangents are $\vec j$ on the right edge and $\vec i$ on the upper edge and they "meet" at the corner point $(1,1)$, which then can not have a unique tangent.

Comment: $f \circ \gamma: (-\epsilon, 0) \to \mathbb{R}^{2}$ and $f \circ \gamma: (0, \epsilon) \to \mathbb{R}^{2}$ are not tangent vectors, but their derivatives are.  Because we know that smooth curves $\gamma$ in a manifold give rise to tangent vectors by considering derivations defined by $\gamma'(t_0)f=(f\circ \gamma)'(t_0).$

Comment: I suppose you are invoking the Inverse Function Theorem to conclude that $\text{d}f$ is an isomorphism. The statement of that theorem is that *if* $\text{d}F$, where $F \colon \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$, is invertible at a point $p \in \mathbb R ^2$, then it is invertible in a neighbourhood. But does such a point exist? Since the (boundary of the) square is not a smooth manifold the standard "the differential of a differentiable map is a isomorphism" does not apply, right?